# connecting laptop to video projector in win 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, video, projector

i have connected my laptop to the video projector. all things are fine and there is not any problem for connecting laptop to video projector. but after opening up a presentation and pressing f5 to play it or playing a video clip and double click for full screen and in some cases suddenly, after some minutes (about 2 min) projector while is showing video clip or presentation, suddenly displaying the video/presentation stops and just shows desktop wallpaper. 
note: laptop keep running video/presentation property after that problem happening but projector fails to showing display. 
shows this:
[image]

i use of win+p and select duplicate but it seems this option be changes to extend while opening programs.

Comment: What presentation software are you using?

Comment: @CharlieRB power point 2016

Comment: You have not given any detail on the laptop, but my guess is it is probably recognizing the projector as a projector, not a monitor. That may be why it changes. Another big factor is slideshow settings in PowerPoint. What is the setting under `multiple monitors`?

Comment: @CharlieRB i did not configured power point settings. can you tell me more? what about playing video clips? i use of media player classic. i have middle range laptop with 1 gb graphic 2 gb ram and a  weak cpu unit. i just use that for presentations and playing movies. its name is gateway.

Comment: This isn't a teaching site. There are lots of resources on the Internet to learn how to use PowerPoint. Here is one that may help you get started - [How to Set Up a Slideshow in PowerPoint 2016](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/powerpoint/how-to-set-up-a-slideshow-in-powerpoint-2016/).